# Spring MVC - how to map lookup path to the produces values

Tags: java, spring

If this is a method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json", 
    "application/xml"}, value="/myService")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity myMethod(...) {
...
}
```

In a another class I have the lookup path `/myService` and I want to get the values in the produces list in the method above: `application/json` and `application/xml`. Is it possible to get access to the values in the produces list using some of Spring MVC's classes?

Comment: You can use reflection, but I don't think that is a good idea. What is your requirement and its purpose?

Comment: If the user tries to access the service with the wrong media type and a 406 is returned, I want to send back some possible suggestions. The suggestions are based on their current request and the possible media types defined in the produces list.

Comment: That should be implemented as an [HTTP OPTIONS request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This peace of code might be doing what you want (or at least point you to the right direction):

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DefaultControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMediaTypeNotAcceptable(
            HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "Supported media types: " + ex.getSupportedMediaTypes(),
                headers, status, request);
    }

}
```

Key fact is that `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` contains supported media types initialized by handler mapper.